# Listview with Checkbox and button using Array adapter in android

Tags: android

I am using custom listview to show the data from sqlite database. My list item 
having textviews, button, checkbox. Please suggest me the adapter which will do the following tasks,

1. all the string values are updated in equalesnt textviews
2. based on the boolean values the check box should be check/ uncheck.
3. when i clicked the button it will take me to the new screen and also pass the button's id.

   Please suggest me what to do now. New ideas also welcome.

   Follow my code.

   ```
       public class GuestListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{
           Context context;
           ArrayList<String> arrayListFirstName;
           ArrayList<String> arrayListLastName;
           ArrayList<String> arrayListGuests;
           ArrayList<String> arrayCustomOne;
           ArrayList<String> arrTicketId;
           private ArrayList<Boolean> checks=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
           public GuestListAdapter(Context mcontext, ArrayList<String> arrListFN,
                   ArrayList<String> arrListLN, ArrayList<String> arrListGuest,
                   ArrayList<String> arrTicketID,ArrayList<String> arrCustOne) {
               arrayListFirstName = arrListFN;
               arrayListLastName = arrListLN;
               arrayListGuests = arrListGuest;
               arrayCustomOne = arrCustOne;
               context = mcontext;

               for (int i = 0; i < arrayListFirstName.size(); i++) {
                   checks.add(i, false);
               }
           }

           @Override
           public int getCount() {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return arrayListFirstName.size();
           }

           @Override
           public Object getItem(int position) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return arrayListFirstName.get(position);
           }

           @Override
           public long getItemId(int position) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return position;
           }

           @Override
           public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               if (view == null) {
                   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guest_list_item, parent, false);
               }

               final String dataModel = (String) arrayListFirstName.get(position);

               TextView txtFirstName = (TextView) view
                       .findViewById(R.id.txt_firstname);
               txtFirstName.setText(arrayListFirstName.get(position));
               TextView txtLastName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_lastname);
               txtLastName.setText(arrayListLastName.get(position));
               TextView txtGuestCount = (TextView) view
                       .findViewById(R.id.txt_guest_count);
               txtGuestCount.setText(arrayListGuests.get(position));
               Button btnInfo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_info);
               // btnInfo.setId(position);
               CheckBox checkBoxCheckins = (CheckBox) view
                       .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxIsCheckedIn);
               checkBoxCheckins.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));

               btnInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       // int id = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());

                       // Log.d("", "Clicked ID "+id);
                       Intent intent = new Intent(context, InfoScreen.class);
                       context.startActivity(intent);
                       System.out.println("Adap button **********");

                   }
               });
               checkBoxCheckins
                       .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                           @Override
                           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                   boolean isChecked) {
                               System.out.println("Adap checked **********");
                               Integer integ = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();

                                  checks.set(integ.intValue(), false);
                           }
                       });
               if (checks.get(position)) {
                   checkBoxCheckins.setChecked(checks.get(position));
                     // do some stuff if wanted..
                   } else {
                       checkBoxCheckins.setChecked(checks.get(position));
                     // do some stuff if wanted..
                   }
               return view;
           }

           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Integer index = (Integer)view.getTag();
                boolean state = checks.get(index.intValue());

                checks.set(index.intValue(), !state);
           }

       }


   this is my setter class

   public class GuestList {

       String mFirstName;
       String mLastName;
       String mTicketI;
       String mGuestCount;

       public String getmFirstName() {
           return mFirstName;
       }

       public void setmFirstName(String mFirstName) {
           this.mFirstName = mFirstName;
       }

       public String getmLastName() {
           return mLastName;
       }

       public void setmLastName(String mLastName) {
           this.mLastName = mLastName;
       }

       public String getmTicketI() {
           return mTicketI;
       }

       public void setmTicketI(String mTicketI) {
           this.mTicketI = mTicketI;
       }

       public String getmGuestCount() {
           return mGuestCount;
       }

       public void setmGuestCount(String mGuestCount) {
           this.mGuestCount = mGuestCount;
       }

   }
   ```

   In listview class sending arraylist like this,

   ```
   cursorAdapter = new GuestListAdapter(GuestListScreen.this,
               arrFirstName, arrLastName, arrGuests, arrTicketId, arrCustomOne);
       listViewGuests.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use BaseAdapter for this. create one class call MyAdapter and extend BaseAdater. in that class override the required method. and in the getView method of the Class inflate your xml file and put the data according to the positon.

if values are coming from the database then take the Cursor and iterate it and get the required value.

hope this helps

Comment: HI I added my code please tell me now what to change.Here I want to change the checkbox based on the true or false.

Comment: add the code which give data to this adapter. like cursor or something